# Data object in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code inside a function:

```
 var setTime = selected[0];
 var selectedTime = {
     ProfessionalUserId: $("#SelectProId").text()
     , Date: selectedDate
     , SetTime: setTime
     , Time: null
 };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: selectedTime,
    url: '@Url.Action("SetAvailableAppointments", "ScheduleView")',
    dataType: "json",
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
            if (data === true) {
               $("#successfulAppt").show();
             }
    },
    error: function (err) {

   }
```

})

The **selected[0]** set a string value that represets a time, i.e. "11:00:00" or "10:15:00, etc...

the **selectedTime** object matches a server side POCO object which is in the signature of the receiving method.

The problem is that if i create the **selectedTime** object like this with the ***SetTime*** property:

```
var setTime = selected[0];
var selectedTime = {
    ProfessionalUserId: $("#SelectProId").text()
    , Date: selectedDate
    , SetTime: setTime
    , Time: null
};
```

the receiving method receives a null object.

if i create the same object **selectedTime** this way:

```
var setTime = selected[0];
var selectedTime = {
     ProfessionalUserId: $("#SelectProId").text()
     , Date: selectedDate
     //, SetTime: setTime
     , Time: null
};
```

without the ***SetTime*** property the receiving method accepts the object.

***SetTime*** is being set to a string value.  I have proved this step through the code with chrome develper tools.

Here is the server side object

```
public class AvailableTime
    {
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get;
            set;

        }
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
        public string TimeLiteral
        {
            get
            {
                return Time.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string SetTime { get; set; }
        public int ProfessionalUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the receiving method:

```
public ActionResult SetAvailableAppointments(AvailableTime setTime)
        {
            if (setTime == null)
                return View();

....

}
```

Comment: where is selectedDate being initialized?

Comment: further up in the code.  I am setting it from another value in control and it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but in your `success` function, you name your input parameter `result` but then refer to it as `data`.

Comment: check the headers your developer tools - are they all getting passed to your server correctly?

Comment: thanks yes unrelated, i copied the if statement from other code and didn't change it, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to change your ajax call to set your parameter this way:

```
data: { setTime: selectedTime },
```

That works because your function parameter is named `setTime`, and you created an object called `selectedTime` like this:

```
var selectedTime = {
    ProfessionalUserId: $("#SelectProId").text()
    , Date: selectedDate
    , SetTime: setTime
    , Time: null
};
```

Comment: I need all the properties on the object to passed back to me.

Comment: Isn't `selectedTime` the object with all your properties?

Comment: actually - if you're doing conversion into an object you are probably correct

Comment: Thanks!!!! I renamed the setTime to newAppt in the receiving method signature and it worked perfectly.  Didn't even think the names were causing issues.